# 'input in flex scanner failed' error occur when compile uboot

Tags: c, u-boot

I encounter the 'input in flex scanner failed' error when i try to build the uboot code.
    This is the whole console log:

```
gan.liu@ubuntu:~/work/PROCESSOR_SDK_VISION_03_06_00_00/ti_components/os_tools/linux/u-boot/u-boot$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/tda/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- dra7xx_evm_vision_config V=1
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig dra7xx_evm_vision_config
scripts/kconfig/conf  --defconfig=arch/../configs/dra7xx_evm_vision_defconfig Kconfig
input in flex scanner failed
make[1]: *** [dra7xx_evm_vision_defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [dra7xx_evm_vision_config] Error 2
gan.liu@ubuntu:~/work/PROCESSOR_SDK_VISION_03_06_00_00/ti_components/os_tools/linux/u-boot/u-boot$ make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/tda/gcc-linaro-5.3-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- dra7xx_evm_vision_config V=1
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig dra7xx_evm_vision_config
  cc -Wp,-MD,scripts/kconfig/.zconf.tab.o.d -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -I/usr/include/ncursesw   -DCURSES_LOC="<ncurses.h>" -DLOCALE  -Iscripts/kconfig -c -o scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  cc  -o scripts/kconfig/conf scripts/kconfig/conf.o scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
scripts/kconfig/conf  --defconfig=arch/../configs/dra7xx_evm_vision_defconfig Kconfig
**errno: 21.**
input in flex scanner failed
make[1]: *** [dra7xx_evm_vision_defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [dra7xx_evm_vision_config] Error 2
gan.liu@ubuntu:~/work/PROCESSOR_SDK_VISION_03_06_00_00/ti_components/os_tools/linux/u-boot/u-boot$
```

I get the "errno:21" info by adding printf in the following snippet:

```
/* Gets input and stuffs it into "buf".  number of characters read, or YY_NULL,
 * is returned in "result".
 */
#ifndef YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
    errno=0; \
    while ( (result = read( fileno(zconfin), (char *) buf, max_size )) < 0 ) \
    { \
        if( errno != EINTR) \
        { \
            printf("errno: %d.\n", errno); \
            YY_FATAL_ERROR( "input in flex scanner failed" ); \
            break; \
        } \
        errno=0; \
        clearerr(zconfin); \
    }\
\

#endif
```

The error code '21' stands for

```
#define EISDIR      21  /* Is a directory */
```

Please kindly help me solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It's all because a mistake.

As i add a new foler for a custom board, i add the corresponding source Kconfig line in some where.
By mistake, i added the new board folder path instead the new Kconfig file path.

Damn carelessness